# Dual of tensor product

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, tensor-products

I'm researching about Distribution of Algebra, and come up with a small lemma, which states that

> Suppose $k$ is a commutative ring with $1$ and $M,N$ are two projective $k$-modules such that $M$ is finitely presented. Take $0 \neq x \in M \otimes N$. Prove that there exists $\mu \in M^*$ such that $(\mu \otimes id_N)x \neq 0$. (Here $M^* = Hom(M, k)$ and $id_N$ is the identity map from N to N)

Some of the assumption might be superfluous. I hope anyone can give me any hint. I really appreciate it.